# Send an Email if User's OneDrive Usage Exceeds Threshold

Tags: excel, powershell, onedrive

I'm working to get emailed any time a user's OneDrive Exceeds 95% storage quota to keep abreast of storage needs. I've got the first part down (get the list, calculate percentage of usage, and export as .xlsx)and was trying through Power Automate to finish the conditional email (if a user has over 95% used, email myself), but can't seem to get it. I'm still learning to code, so this would be a big help!

My current code:

```
 $adminUPN=""  
 $orgName=""
 $userCredential = Get-Credential -UserName $adminUPN
 Connect-SPOService -Url https://$orgName-admin.sharepoint.com -Credential $userCredential

#Get a list of OneDrive for Business sites in the tenant sorted by the biggest consumer of quota

 $ODFBSites = Get-SPOSite -IncludePersonalSite $True -Limit All -Filter "Url -like '-my.sharepoint.com/personal/'" | Select Owner, Title, URL, StorageQuota, StorageUsageCurrent | Sort 
 StorageUsageCurrent -Desc

 $TotalODFBGBUsed = [Math]::Round(($ODFBSites.StorageUsageCurrent | Measure-Object -Sum).Sum /1024,2)

 $Report = [System.Collections.Generic.List[Object]]::new()

 ForEach ($Site in $ODFBSites) {

     $ReportLine   = [PSCustomObject]@{
       Owner       = $Site.Title
       Email       = $Site.Owner
       PercentUsed = [Math]::Round(($Site.StorageUsageCurrent/$Site.StorageQuota * 100),4)
       QuotaGB     = [Math]::Round($Site.StorageQuota/1024,2) 
       UsedGB      = [Math]::Round($Site.StorageUsageCurrent/1024,4)}
     $Report.Add($ReportLine) }
$Report | Export-Excel C:\users\xxxx\desktop\OneDriveUsage.xlsx
```

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You could use the same `$Report` array to send yourself an email with a table of users that exceed the threshold:

```
$over95 = @($Report | Where-Object { $_.PercentUsed -gt 95 })
if ($over95.Count) {
    # create a Here-String template to use for mailing yourself
    $mailTemplate = @"
<html><head>
<style>
    body, table {font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 10pt; color: #000000;}
    table {border: 1px solid black; border-collapse: collapse;}
    th {border: 1px solid black; background: #dddddd; padding: 3px;}
    td {border: 1px solid black; padding: 3px;}
</style>
</head><body>
These users have more than 95% of storage used.<br />
@@TABLE@@
<br />
</body></html>
"@

    # create a nice HTML table from the data in $over95
    $table = ($over95 | ConvertTo-Html -As Table -Fragment) -join [environment]::NewLine
    # create a Hashtable for splatting the parameters to the Send-MailMessage cmdlet
    $mailParams = @{
        To         = 'YOU@yourdomain.com'
        From       = 'YOU@yourdomain.com'
        SmtpServer = 'smtp.yourdomain.com'
        Subject    = 'Users that exceed 95% storage in OneDrive'
        Body       = $mailTemplate -replace '@@TABLE@@', $table
        BodyAsHtml = $true
        # more parameters can go here
    }
    # send the email
    Send-MailMessage @mailParams
}
```